# List Iterator - Not working

Tags: java

I've below code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class IteratorExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> listnames = new ArrayList<String>();
        listnames.add("Tom");
        listnames.add("Finn");
        listnames.add("Harry");

        ListIterator<String> iteratorNames = listnames.listIterator();
        while (iteratorNames.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iteratorNames);
        }

    }

}
```

When I execute, I am getting strange output like below(which differs everytime when I run the program):

```
java.util.ArrayList$ListItr@a200d0c
java.util.ArrayList$ListItr@a200d0c
java.util.ArrayList$ListItr@a200d0c
java.util.ArrayList$ListItr@a200d0c
java.util.ArrayList$ListItr@a200d0c
```

Also the program is running infinitely.

Why it is not printing the list values?

Comment: System.out.println(iteratorNames.next());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the below line:

```
System.out.println(iteratorNames);
```

To:

```
System.out.println(iteratorNames.next());
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at the iterator itself.

use

```
iteratorNames.next()
```

to get the next item.

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting strange output like below

It's just printing the memory adress of the object using the `toString()` default implementation of the object class.

```
public String toString() {
   return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

> Also the program is running infinitely.

As other answers stated, you have to use `next()`(i.e `System.out.println(iteratorNames.next());`) for two reasons :

1. It allows you to get the element in the list while iterating it
2. It advances the cursor position of the iterator

That's why your program runs indefinitely, because the cursor is still on the first position on your list, so `hasNext()` will always returns true.

Using `next()` the program looks like :

```
while (iteratorNames.hasNext()) {
        String element = iteratorNames.next(); //now you can do what you want with this element
        System.out.println(element);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have already mentioned how you use an `Iterator`--by querying it to see if it has a next value and then grabbing it via `next()` if it does.

However, you have the option of avoiding those low-level details altogether through a nice syntactic abstraction:

```
for (String name : listnames) {
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

Give it a shot. In my opinion, it was one of the most helpful features of Java 5. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) is more information on it.

Answer (score 1):

In your program `System.out.println(iteratorNames);`  it will call toString() of Object class that will returns a string representation of the object (see implementation on toString())

```
public String toString() {
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

That is why you are getting output like `java.util.ArrayList$ListItr@a200d0c`.

call **next()** It will returns the next element in the list. as follows:

```
System.out.println(iteratorNames.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
System.out.println((String)iteratorNames.next());
```